# can't update ubuntu, unreachable repositories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update

My Ubuntu install can't reach the repository urls archive.ubuntu.com and ca.archive.ubuntu.com.

I've tried updating through the command line and the update manager.

Are they laggy lately or down?

When I boot back into Windows 7 I can ping the repositories, but it takes like 30 seconds for the ping to be acknowledged.

I feel like the ping is timing out on Ubuntu when using the ping command or apt.

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 32-bit

Update: this has turned into an advanced network problem probably involving the bind server on my ubuntu gateway

The Windows partition on the client can ping archive.ubuntu.com but the name resolves after 30 seconds.

The Ubuntu partition cannot ping archive.ubuntu.com the lookup fails.

I can ping archive.ubuntu.com from the ubuntu gateway without problems.

Based on this I think the gateway is causing the problem due to an incorrect locally defined version of archive.ubuntu.com, which after it fails to resolv after 30 seconds turns to the bind server for a successful lookup.

To find the answer, I'm looking for the difference between a local dns lookup on Ubuntu and a remote dns lookup.  The answer could also be in bind.

Before I start pasting config files are there any ideas?

Keep in mind this setup was working flawlessly for 6 months resolving everything.  Only now that I've booted into my 2nd partition, Ubuntu, did I realize that I couldn't resolv the update archive names, including ca.archive.ubuntu.com, us.archive.ubuntu.com and archive.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only the first ping that's a problem, it looks more like a name lookup problem.   In that case you probably have a broken DNS setup.  You should check /etc/resolv.conf and (if appropriate) the settings you are getting from your DHCP server to make sure they actually work (e.g. ping the DNS servers by IP address).   If all pings take 30s, your networking setup is horribly broken (this may or may not include your DNS configuration).

For comparison, I get around 0.18 second ping response from ca.archive.ubuntu.com; I'm in Europe.

Comment: you know whats messed up?  from my linux gateway I can ping that url no problem.  I'm running Bind on it, and my client win7/ubuntu has never had problems pinging/vising a website/resolving names before.  Its just this repository name that takes 30 seconds to resolv from my client.

Comment: AND my gateway uses nameserver 127.0.0.1 as its dns server lol...

Comment: I can ping a random name if I do a google search and paste names into the cmd prompt.  Meh

Comment: Use the `host` command to do name lookups of the hostname (not URL!) specifying the nameserver's IP address as the second argument of the host command (e.g. `time host archive.ubuntu.com 8.8.8.8`).    Figure out how the time this takes depends on which IP address you specified for the nameserver.     If your gateway is the only DNS server which is slow to complete a successful lookup, it's very likely that one of the DNS servers configured there (in BIND's `named.conf` file) is incorrect or unreachable (double check with `host` again).